# Creating and filling in an extra column in a Dataframe based on values in another Dataframe that I have?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

DSo, I'm trying to compare two dataframes. One of them is a dataframe based on data from a csv file, and the other is that dataframe with the duplicates dropped.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

file1 = 'file1.csv'

file1Dataframe = pd.read_csv(file1, low_memory=False)

ddfile1 = file1Dataframe.drop_duplicates('Stop')
```

I want to add two columns to the file1Dataframe and fill them out with data from the ddfile1.

For example, when a value in one column, "Location" matches a value in the column "Location" in ddfile1, I want to add the data from the row of the matching "Location" in ddfile1 into the row of the "Location" in file1Dataframe. Let's say that the data I want is from the column "Latitude", and I want to move it to the new column "ConstantLatitude"

file1Dataframe

| "Latitude" | "Longitude" | "Location" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 68.3242 | 42.3435 | LA |
| 94.233 | 34.4332 | ND |

ddfile1

| "Latitude" | "Longitude" | "Location" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 56.2442 | 45.6664 | LA |
| 78.4433 | 90.424 | ND |

After the Code runs

file1Dataframe

| "Latitude" | "Longitude" | "Location" | "ConsLatitude" | "ConsLongitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 68.3242 | 42.3435 | LA | 56.2442 | 45.6664 |
| 94.233 | 34.4332 | ND | 78.4433 | 90.424 |

I want to do this for every single row in file1Dataframe, comparing it to every single column in ddfile1.

How do I achieve this?

I tried using the .where function, but it didn't help.

Comment: Try using pandas merge. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: Should be less costly than the grouping solution I post !

Comment: @Zelemist How would I fix a "transform must return a scalar value for each group" error? And If I do decide to use merge, how would I do it? I don't know how I would do it based on Location.

Comment: I'll update to fix this error, and adding a merge solution, which in my opinion is better

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

Merging is a better and quicker option, I'll keep the grouping option for historic sake.

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csvfile = StringIO(
"""Latitude\tLongitude\tLocation
68.3242\t42.3435\tLA
65.3242\t40.3435\tLA
94.233\t34.4332\tND""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = '\t', engine='python')

csvfile = StringIO(
"""Latitude\tLongitude\tLocation
56.2442\t45.6664\tLA
78.4433\t90.424\tND""")

df2 = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = '\t', engine='python')

df.merge(df2, how='left', on='Location', suffixes=("", "_cons"))
Out[65]: 
   Latitude  Longitude Location  Latitude_cons  Longitude_cons
0   68.3242    42.3435       LA        56.2442         45.6664
1   65.3242    40.3435       LA        56.2442         45.6664
2   94.2330    34.4332       ND        78.4433         90.4240
```

### Grouping

Grouping can work. But it's tedious, inelegant, and merging option should be considered.

```py
df.loc[:, "ConsLatitude"] = df.groupby('Location')['Location']
.transform(lambda x : df2.query('Location == @x.name').loc[:, "Latitude"].iloc[0])

df.loc[:, "ConsLongitude"] = df.groupby('Location')['Location']
.transform(lambda x : df2.query('Location == @x.name').loc[:, "Longitude"].iloc[0])

df
Out[188]: 
   Latitude  Longitude Location  ConsLatitude  ConsLongitude
0   68.3242    42.3435       LA       56.2442        45.6664
1   65.3242    40.3435       LA       56.2442        45.6664
2   94.2330    34.4332       ND       78.4433        90.4240
```